# multi-select dropdown Bokeh

Tags: python, bokeh

I know that there are a bunch of widgets available in Bokeh, here:

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/widgets.html

How can I integrate Bokeh Dropdown Menu with MultiSelect (or extend the Dropdown) in order to have a Multi-Select Dropdown? Is there anything built-in?

My expected result is a dropdown which one can select/deselect multiple options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write you own custom Bokeh model extension using TypeScript. See [Extending Bokeh](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/extensions.html) for more information. Scroll down for links to some nice examples. You will need to install nodejs on your system to be able to compile TypeScript.

If the widget height is your main consideration than you could think of replacing the MultiSelect with CheckboxButtonGroup.